# Applescript get all undelivered iMessage?

Tags: applescript, imessage

Can anybody tell me how to collect all undelivered messages on Mac OSX "Messages App" using AppleScript?

My idea was to analyze the UI elements of the window but it doesn't work well

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found out the information is stored in the SQLite database at ~/Library/Messages/chat.db
[image]
I get everything I want here...